# ioctl - invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, driver

I  have

```
#define IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG _IO(MAJOR_NUM, 0) 
#define IOCTL_DEALLOC_MSG _IO(MAJOR_NUM, 1)
```

in a header file.

and in the driver file I wrote:

```
struct file_operations memory_fops = {
  unlocked_ioctl: device_ioctl,
  open: memory_open,
  release: memory_release
};


int memory_init(void) {
  int result;

  /* Registering device */
  result = register_chrdev(MAJOR_NUM, "memory", &memory_fops);
  if (result < 0) {
    printk("<1>memory: cannot obtain major number %d\n", MAJOR_NUM);
    return result;
  }

  allocfunc();

  printk("<1>Inserting memory module\n");
  return 0;

}

int device_ioctl(struct inode *inode,   /* see include/linux/fs.h */
         struct file *file, /* ditto */
         unsigned int ioctl_num,    /* number and param for ioctl */
         unsigned long ioctl_param)
{
    /* 
     * Switch according to the ioctl called 
     */
    printk ( "<l> inside ioctl \n" );
    switch (ioctl_num) {
    case IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG:
        allocfunc();
        break;
    case IOCTL_DEALLOC_MSG:
        deallocfunc();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I created the character file like

```
mknod /dev/memory c 60 0
```

the app call fails

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * memfile;

    /* Opening the device parlelport */
    memfile=fopen("memory","r+");
    if ( memfile <0) {
        printf ( " cant open file \n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* We remove the buffer from the file i/o */
    int ret_val;
    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        if ( strcmp (argv[1], "mem" ) ==0 ) {


            ret_val = ioctl(memfile, IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG);

            if (ret_val < 0) {
                printf("ioctl failed. Return code: %d, meaning: %s\n", ret_val, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

when i run the app i get "ioctl failed. Return code: -1, meaning: Invalid argument" in : strerror(errno)

printk:

```
Inserting memory module
```

fyi, I experimented with "/dev/memory" "memory" different names and major number combinations - but in vain.

Comment: what is the value of `MAJOR_NUM`?  are you sure 60 is not already in use by another driver?  i.e. what does your init_module() function look like, and if it calls `register_chrdev()` as it should, what's the result?  also, you don't even show the call to `strerror()`....

Comment: MAJOR_NUM is 60 and is not used by another driverint memory_init(void) {
  int result;

  /* Registering device */
  result = register_chrdev(MAJOR_NUM, "memory", &memory_fops);
  if (result < 0) {
    printk("<1>memory: cannot obtain major number %d\n", MAJOR_NUM);
    return result;
  }

  allocfunc();

  printk("<1>Inserting memory module\n");
  return 0;

}
---app----------ret_val = ioctl(memfile, IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG);

            if (ret_val < 0) {
                printf("ioctl failed. Return code: %d, meaning: %s\n", ret_val, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }

Comment: OK, so maybe you could edit that into your code above?  And also please add all the code between the `fopen()` up to and including the call to `strerror()`(especially show if you checked the result from the `fopen()`), and show any console output from the time the module is loaded up until the time of the `ioctl()` call (i.e. I want to see the `printk()` in there and any other related output.

Comment: I updated the original post with init, app and printk.

Comment: Why there is a call to sub-routine `allocFunc()` in initializing the module? Shouldn't be the function is called when process do a ioctl on device. Since you are allocating isn't macro `IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG` is defined with read/write permission.

Comment: you mean I should do _IORW ? but I have nothing to receive or return back to user space. btw, this is just a test program to being with. my logic is still not there so plz ignore allocFunc . Thx.

Comment: You are now showing that your user program is opening something called `"memory"` for read and write in the current working directory where it was invoked, yet you show having created a device node called `/dev/memory1`.  I'm guessing you'll find that you now have a file called `memory` in your working directory, and of course trying to do any `ioctl()` call on a non-device file will fail with `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a `FILE*` to the `ioctl()` function, while it expects a file descriptor, that is an `int`.

It should at the very least generate a big warning saying that you are converting a pointer to integer without a cast, doesn't it?

There are two obvious solutions:

1. Use the `fileno()` function to get the file descriptor from the `FILE*`. It should be something like `ioctl(fileno(memfile), IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG)`.
2. Use `open()` instead of `fopen()`. This one is the preferred solution if you are writing low level code, as you avoid the additional abstraction layer that `FILE*` imposes (all the buffering stuff and so).

Comment: Damn!  I completely missed that one!

Comment: @furion: You are welcome! Try compiling with `-Wall`. It should give a warning. Maybe you forgot the `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` and you are getting the automatic function declaration; if that's the case you should have a warning, also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to postulate that changing `fopen("memory")` to `fopen("/dev/memory1")` will fix the initial problem with your code.

@SunEric also points out in a comment on your question that you have a call to `allocFunc()` in your driver's initialization function (`memory_init()`), and yet that seems to be what you want your `IOCTL_ALLOC_MSG` to do.  That may well be the next problem you need to straighten out.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I experimented with "/dev/memory" "memory" different names and major number combinations - but in vain. I have tried with allocFunc() without etc., plz ignore minor issues. Iam able to see the printk in memory_init() successfully.